# Windows Batch: acessing variables from inside FOR loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

Im trying to do this rather elementary thing in a DOS batch:

```
@echo off
set _sets=^
RO:111:Rondonia,^
AC:112:Acre,^
AM:113:Amazonas,^
RR:114:Roraima
set _family_name=MyFamily
FOR %%i IN (%_sets%) DO (
    echo %%i ----- %_family_name%
)
```

Output:

```
RO:111:Rondonia -----
AC:112:Acre -----
AM:113:Amazonas -----
RR:114:Roraima -----
```

After the ----- is supposed to appear "MyFamily", but instead nothing appears.

How do I access variables set outside a FOR loop from within it?  I have no idea why the _family_name variable is not visible inside the for loop.  I'm somewhat new to batch scripts.  I'm used to C++ and Java programming, thus most likely my thinking does not apply to the batch realm.

I also need to split the string triplets "AA:NNN:AAAAAA" into three individual variables.  I tried to come up with a nested for loop, but I couldn't tackle this problem.

The example was made simple for clarity.  The actual Batch is more complex than that.  I have to access 10-12 variables from within the loop.  So please consider this aspect before answering.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example works here -- I get `RO:111:Rondonia ----- MyFamily` and so forth.

Comment: Jim, maybe it was something else in my more complex batch.  Your solution with the exclamations solved the puzzle.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If `_family_name` is actually being set within another (outer) loop, you'll need to enable delayed expansion with something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for ...
  set foo=bar
  for ...
    echo !foo!
  )
)
```

Note that you access the variable with `!exclamations!` instead of `%percents%` there.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps you:

```
FOR /f %%a "tokens=1-4 delims=," IN ("%_sets%") DO (
    echo %%a ----- %_family_name%
    echo %%b ----- %_family_name%
    echo %%c ----- %_family_name%
    echo %%d ----- %_family_name%
)
```

Comment: Those variables created out of thin air (b, c and d) bother me a lot, but the solution worked.  Fine, thanks!

Comment: The `tokens=` section can have `tokens=1,3,5,6` or `tokens=1-10` for 10 tokens.  Each token is a segment of the string separated by the characters in the `delims=` section.  The metavariables are sequential from the one used.

Comment: Thanks, @foxidrive, for the explanation on the "thin air" (or meta- in your educated speech :) ) variables.  Is the sequence an ASCII sequence?

Comment: Yes, it is in ASCII sequence.